# Вызов пользовательских функций в шаблоне(php)

Tags: php, логика, шаблонизаторы

Добрый вечер. Задумался над тем как реализовать вызов своей функции в шаблоне.
Прямой пример - функции get_footer и get_header в wordpress. Они вызываются в шаблоне, но само описание работы функции хранится в файлах движка, как строится эта обвязка?

Т.е. для примера:
Есть файл myfunc.php - в нем описание работы функции.
И index.php где идет вызов это функции.

Как это сделать не используя include / require ?

Comment: 1) А чем вам не нравится `include`? 2) Можете, конечно, сделать очень замороченную структуру, только... просто посмотрите index.php в корне WP

Answer (score 0):

Никак.

И WordPress работает через require. Функция get_header() вызывает locate_template(), она вызывает load_template(), а вот она уже использует require или require_once.